# In Qt drawPoint method does not plot anything if negative valued parameters are supplies

Tags: qt, qpainter

in Qt creator drawPoint() method does not put point if negative valued parameters are passed
following is code for Bresenham's algorithm.but, it is not working in qt creator.it just plots circle in one quadrant.

```
Bresenham::Bresenham(QWidget*parent):QWidget(parent)  
{}

void  Bresenham::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)  
{  
     Q_UNUSED(e);  
     QPainter qp(this);  
     drawPixel(&qp);  
}  
void  Bresenham::drawPixel(QPainter *qp)  
{  
    QPen pen(Qt::red,2,Qt::SolidLine);  
    qp->setPen(pen);  
    int x=0,y,d,r=100;  
    y=r;  
    d=3-2*r;  
    do  
    {  
       qp->drawPoint(x,y);  
       qp->drawPoint(y,x);  
       qp->drawPoint(y,-x);  
       qp->drawPoint(x,-y);  
       qp->drawPoint(-x,-y);  
       qp->drawPoint(-y,-x);  
       qp->drawPoint(-x,y);  
       qp->drawPoint(-y,x);
       if(d<0)  
       {  
          d=d+4*x+6;  
       }  
       else  
       {  
          d=d+(4*x-4*y)+10;  
          y=y-1;  
       }  
       x=x+1;  
      }while(x<y); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to translate the Qt coordinate system to the classic cartesian one. Choose a new center `QPoint orig` and replace all

```
qp->drawPoint(x,y);
```

with

```
qp->drawPoint(orig + QPoint(x,y));
```

The [Qt coordinates system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/coordsys.html) origin is at `(0,0)` and the y-axis is inverted. For instance, a segment from `A(2,7)` to `B(6,1)` look like this:

[image]

Notice how there is only the positive-x, positive-y quadrant. For simplicity assume **that no negative coordinates exist.**

**Note:**

For performance reasons it is better to compute all the points first and then draw them all using

```
QPainter::drawPoints ( const QPoint * points, int pointCount );
```

Comment: @user3198176 Hi. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this